# sharp architecture contrib transaction attribute in windows service

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

For some reason this:

```
[Transaction]
public void DoSomething()
{
    ...
}
```

does not work I still have to explicitly use the transaction like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var tx = NHibernateSession.Current.BeginTransaction())
    {
        ....
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why?

I am using something like this to bootstrap stuff:

```
_container = new WindsorContainer();
ComponentRegistrar.AddComponentsTo(_container);

...

ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(_container));

ComponentRegistrar.AddComponentsTo(_container, typeof(NHibernateTransactionManager));

NHibernateSession.Init(new ThreadSessionStorage(),
        new[] { "Bla.Domain.dll" },
        new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
        "NHibernate.config");
```

Answer (score 1):

As Doan said the component that had the method is not proxied.

Since the method is not virtual, I am assuming that your class is implementing an interface. make sure that you have the dependency in the class calling DoSomething defined as the interface and not the implementing class.

if you debug the code, and check the run time type of the object, it should be a castle proxy

for more details check the trouble shooting section on Sharp Architecture contrib wiki
https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture-Contrib/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks Seif. Btw s#arp seems to be quite dormant recently. Do you think that will change?

Comment: yes, been really busy and not using it at work. picking up soon

Comment: No need to switch to EF5 then? (-:

Comment: @SeifAttar - I am working with MVC5 and Web API 2.2 in this project, we are using both MVC controller and Web API Controller, the challenge is [Transaction] attribute works fine for MVC controller but it does not work with Web API controller. I did not find support of web API from Sharp Architecture. Is there any such support available or planned? I tried some workaround but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this kind of problem is caused by the failure of invoking the dynamic proxy that provides the transaction management service. Two of the most common errors are:

- The method cannot be proxied: most likely not implement any interface method, or the object was not proxied.
- The method was called from the same class, which bypassed all proxies.

Edit:

I guess you use Castle Windsor as IoC container. The `[Transaction]` decoration requires the Automatic Transaction Management Facility in order to work. If you successfully configured the facility, i.e. you made `[Transaction]` work in one method, but not other, then the answer above applies. If all Transaction decoration failed to work, then you have to review the configuration of the facility first.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please be a bit more specific. Which method etc.?

Comment: The method in question, i.e. the method that you put the `[Transaction]` decoration on but failed to initiate a transaction, like `DoSomething()` in your example.

Comment: I would assume that the transaction manager is defined via: ComponentRegistrar.AddComponentsTo(_container, typeof(NHibernateTransactionManager));